# Remove surrounding markup when prettifying symbols

Tags: latex, vim-emulation, prettify-symbols-mode

Is there any way to get Emacs to hide surrounding markup when prettifying? That's a feature I really miss from Vim.  For example, when editing LaTeX in Vim, the conceal feature can be made to replace not just a string with an associated character, but also hide the surrounding math markup: `$\rightarrow$` gets rendered as just a plain arrow (no dollar signs).  Is this possible in Emacs?